# Integrating Kafka with Apache Calcite

Tags: java, sql, stream, apache-kafka, apache-calcite

I'm trying to integrate calcite with Kafka, I refrenced CsvStreamableTable.

Each ConsumerRecord is convert to Object[] using the fowlloing code:

```
static class ArrayRowConverter extends RowConverter<Object[]> {
    private List<Schema.Field> fields;

    public ArrayRowConverter(List<Schema.Field> fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    @Override
    Object[] convertRow(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> consumerRecord) {
        Object[] objects = new Object[fields.size()+1];
        int i = 0 ;
        objects[i++] = consumerRecord.timestamp();
        for(Schema.Field field : this.fields) {
            Object obj = consumerRecord.value().get(field.name());
            if( obj instanceof Utf8 ){
                objects[i ++] = obj.toString();
            }else {
                objects[i ++] = obj;
            }
        }
        return objects;
    }
}
```

Enumerator is implemented as following,one thread is constantly polling records from kafka and put them into a queue, getRecord() method poll from that queue:

```
public E current() {
    return current;
}

public boolean moveNext() {
for(;;) {
    if(cancelFlag.get()) {
        return false;
    }
    ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record = getRecord();
    if(record ==  null) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        continue;
    }
    current = rowConvert.convertRow(record);
    return true;
    }
}
```

I tested `SELECT STREAM * FROM Kafka.clicks`, it works fine.
rowtime is the first column explicitly added,and the value is record Timestamp of Kafka.

But when I tried

```
SELECT STREAM FLOOR(rowtime TO HOUR) 
AS rowtime,ip,COUNT(*) AS c FROM KAFKA.clicks  GROUP BY FLOOR(rowtime TO HOUR), ip
```

It threw exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error while executing SQL "SELECT STREAM FLOOR(rowtime TO HOUR) AS rowtime,ip,COUNT(*) AS c FROM KAFKA.clicks  GROUP BY FLOOR(rowtime TO HOUR), ip": From line 1, column 85 to line 1, column 119: Streaming aggregation requires at least one monotonic expression in GROUP BY clause
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare that the "ROWTIME" column is monotonic. In `MockCatalogReader`, note how "ROWTIME" is declared monotonic in the "ORDERS" and "SHIPMENTS" streams. That’s why some queries in `SqlValidatorTest.testStreamGroupBy()` are valid and others are not. The key method relied up by the validator is `SqlValidatorTable.getMonotonicity(String columnName)`.

Comment: Thanks Julian, is there simple way to declare a column monotonic, or should I just implement as MockTable did?

Comment: @user2283216,  according to this [code snipped](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/53e09688c71b85817a9c382edd573dbcc7e48aa5/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/prepare/RelOptTableImpl.java#L362-L365) it should be enough to define the `rowtime` as the first column (e.g index=0) to ensure its monotonicity.